# Android - How to turn off sound on speak recognition events?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, audio

Android - How to turn off sound on speak recognition events? Next code don't work:

```
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using next code

```
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

solves the problem.